# Using Powershell to copy file from network drive to local drive

Tags: powershell

I have the following code that will look at the modified date and I can copy a file both ran seperately. However, I am still having trouble having the code keep looking at the file and when it detects changes to copy.

```
Get-Childitem "directory goes here" -File | 
Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $date}
Copy-Item -Path 'directory goes here' -Destination 'directory goes here'
```

Can I get some direction as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Yes that's possible.

Comment: You can use the "Get-Item" cmdlet and call the "LastWriteTime" property of the item in your script. `$x = Get-Item C:\modifiedfile` followed by `$x.LastWriteTime` ought to be included in your script.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service.  Do some work on your own and come back when you get stuck with a *specific* problem.

Comment: I'll reference @TheIncorrigible1 here - give it a shot and once you get stuck let us know.  We'll be here to help when you have a real problem, but we aren't going to write it all out for you.

Comment: you changed your question so it doesnt match the title anymore. You will need to ether use a loop (which i dont recommend in this case or a scheduled job that runs every so often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is almost complete on its own.  You can further your pipeline:

```
$UNC = '\\share'
$Path = 'C:\Temp'

Get-ChildItem -Path $UNC |
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date) } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Path
    }
```

Although, an improvement:

```
$Path = 'C:\Temp'
$UNC = Get-ChildItem -Path '\\share' -File
$Local = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File

ForEach ($File in $UNC)
{
    $Compare = $Local | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $File.Name }
    If ($Compare -and $Compare.LastWriteTime -gt $File.LastWriteTime)
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $Path -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this create a folder after a change is detected and copy the file into that folder? I'd like to have the current date/time of when the change was detected the name of the folder created everytime a change is detected

Comment: @Mogheh I updated my answer.  All it does is compare what you give it.  If you need files/folders to exist, you need to figure out that logic on your own.

Comment: Okay so the $Path and $UNC can you advise if I just put the directory or the directory with the file in the directory?

Comment: @Mogheh If you can't understand the logic in the example, it sounds like you need to hire a developer.

Comment: I figured it out. I had a slew of ' at the end of line 2. It works. I will mark this as the answer and open another topic if I need further assistance!